# Number of nodes/edges in a large graph via Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

What is the easiest & most efficient way to count the number of nodes/edges in a large graph via Gremlin?  The best I have found is using the V iterator:

```
gremlin> g.V.gather{it.size()}
```

However, this is not a viable option for large graphs, per the [documentation for V](http://gremlindocs.com/#transform/v):

> The vertex iterator for the graph. Utilize this to iterate through all
>   the vertices in the graph. Use with care on large graphs unless used
>   in combination with a key index lookup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the preferred way to do a count of all vertices would be:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V.count()
==>6
gremlin> g.E.count()
==>6
```

though, I think that on a very large graph `g.V/E` just breaks down no matter what you do.  On a very large graph the best option for doing a count is to use a tool like Faunus(http://thinkaurelius.github.io/faunus/) so that you can leverage the power of Hadoop to do the counts in parallel.

**UPDATE**: The original answer above was for TinkerPop 2.x. For TinkerPop 3.x the answer is largely the same and implies use of [Gremlin Spark](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sparkgraphcomputer) or some provider specific tooling (like [DSE GraphFrames](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2017/05/introducing-dse-graph-frames) for DataStax Graph) that is optimized to do those kinds of large scale traversals.

Comment: Great, thank you! I was thinking the metadata might be tracked & accessible somewhere, but Faunus does sound like a solid alternative.

Comment: I don't know that any graphs track that as metadata explicitly, though if any did it would be specific to the operations of the graph itself.  There is nothing in Blueprints/Gremlin that gets at that count directly, nor does Blueprints expose metadata in any way.  If you found that a graph implementation did have metadata to get you this information you could likely access it by getting the underlying graph with `getRawGraph()`.

Comment: Is it possible to run both g.V.count() and g.E.count() in a single query, and consume the result of both?

Comment: yes, it can be done but note that the same warnings as mentioned in this answer will still apply - only doubly (or more) so because now you're not only reading every vertex but also every edge in the graph. Anyway, a proper answer requires more than what should be written in a stackoverflow comment. it deserves its own question and answer - if you create one and link here i'd be happy to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above, it didn't work for me. For some of you, this may work:

```js
gremlin> g.V.count()
{"detailedMessage":"Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 3, error message : no viable alternative at input 'g.V.'","code":"MalformedQueryException","requestId":"99f749db-c240-9834-aa12-e17bb21e598e"}
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>37
gremlin> g.E().count()
==>45
gremlin>
```

Use `g.V().count` instead of `g.V.count()`. (For those where the other command errors out).

Answer (score 0):

via python:

```
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()
graph_db_uri = 'ws://localhost/gremlin'

      
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection(graph_db_uri,'g'))
count=g.V().hasLabel('node_label').count().next()
print("vertex count: ",count)

count=g.E().hasLabel('edge_label').count().next()
print("edge count: ",count)
```